# send table created in one page to another page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have created country and city as dependable menus. When I select all the dropdown values and click on the display button it should render created html table just below the display button which is illustrated in image below.

For table creation when I click on the display button it loads javascript code  and sends ajax request to another php page. In this php page table is created. How can I render thus created html table in section just below the Display button.

[image: Main Page]

My javascript code in index.php page is

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function tbl_display(){
     var sel_countryid= $("sel_country").val();
          var sel_cityid= $("#sel_city").val();
          var dataString = 'sel_countryid='+ sel_countryid+ '&sel_cityid='+ sel_cityid;  
         alert(dataString);
          if(sel_regionid=='' || sel_lbtype=='')
              {

                  alert("Please enter Valid Data");
              }
           else
           {
                $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "tbl_create.php",
              data: dataString,
              cache: true,
              success: function(html){

              }

              });

           }   

         } 
    </script>
```

I have created table in tbl_create.php page.

How can I use thus created table to render below display button or How can I pass created html table to javascript code and render it to desired section ?

Comment: in the success function add the html to the div where you want the table ` $('#result_div').html(html);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your `ajax` function set the `dataType` to html and in it's success-function put the result out to a `<div>` below your form:

```
 $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "tbl_create.php",
     data: dataString,
     dataType: "html",
     cache: true,
     success: function (html) {
        $("#target").html(html);
     }

 });
```

html:

```
<!-- your form is here -->
<div id="target"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can append the return html table from tbl_create.php using the html() jquery function

so the return must be a string

```
$table = "<table><tr><td>THIS IS A TABLE</td><td>FIRST ROW</td></tr></table>";

return $table
```

if return won't work

try

```
echo $table
```

then in the success function

```
success: function(html){
      $('#appendReturnTable').html(html);
  }
```

that should do the trick hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that in your html page you have a div for your table like this :

```
 <div class="myTable"></div>
```

Then in the success function of your ajax request try this :

```
//....
success: function(html){
     $('.myTable').html(html)
          }
//....
```